# SQL Query username:password

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im creating a webpage for a game server that only had a registration page. All the users has registred and for some dum reason, it saved the password as username:password, so if the username is Meko and password is 1234, the actually password is "Meko:1234"  Im now trying to make a login but im not sure how I should check that password. I have this sql query and tried to add $user_username: in front, but it didnt seem to work:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM account
              WHERE username = '$user_username'
              AND   sha_pass_hash = '$user_password'";
```

It needs to be $user_username:$user_password

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: The answer to your question is `CONCAT()`. The actual answer is to fix your data using a migration script.

Comment: Are you really storing passwords as plain text? This is very dangerous.

Comment: No im not storing passwords as plain text. The passwords is in sha1

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text or some weak hashing method like SHA1.

Comment: are you still having problems?

Comment: I'll answer when I get home. I made this post 2 AM last night and have been on work all day so I havnt been around to test or answer all of your questions :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you on php ?

```
$username = 'Meko';
$user_password = '1234';
$altered_pass = $user_username.':'.$user_password;

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"select * from account where username = ? and sha_pass_hash = ?") ){

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$user_username,sha1($altered_pass));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)){
        //"yup";
    }
    else{
        //"nope";
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Prone to SQL Injection. User should use SQL Parameters or at least sanitize the input.

Comment: Im on PHP but its not working. I've already tried that. It gives me a syntax error, but As Codecaster wrote, I maybe have to use CONCAT(). Im not sure how. I've never heard of it before

Comment: Anything to do with `mysql_query` is historical, it's been removed in PHP 7. Please avoid suggesting it in answers unless it's specifically relevant.

Comment: @tadman what about now mysqli_* , i've updated my answer please review it!

Comment: Getting there, but what you really need is to use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) because escaping things manually is a mess, as you can see here.

Comment: That's the ticket.

Comment: OP said that what was stored in the `user_sha_pass` column was the SHA1 hash/digest of `'Meko:1234'`. The return from **`sha1( $altered_pass )`** is what needs to be passed as bind value to the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

If what you have stored in the database is an SHA1 checksum, then that's what you will need to compare.

The details are pretty sketchy.

Assuming that the row was saved into the database as

```
 INSERT INTO `account` (`username`, `sha_pass_hash`, ...
 VALUES ('Meko', SHA1('Meko:1234'), ...
```

Then to check for the existence of that row, given:

```
 $user_username = 'Meko' ;
 $user_password = '1234' ;
```

if those are the values you want to pass into the database query, then

```
 $sql = 'SELECT ... 
           FROM account a
          WHERE a.username      = ?
            AND a.sha_pass_hash = SHA1( CONCAT( ? ,':', ? )';

 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->bindValue(1,$user_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->bindValue(2,$user_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->bindValue(3,$user_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->execute();
 if( $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     // matching row found
 } else {
     // no matching row found
 }
 $sth->closeCursor();
```

---

If you didn't use the MySQL SHA1 function and used some other function to calculcate the hash, then use that same function when you do the check.

That is, if the row was inserted by a statement of a form more like

```
INSERT INTO account (username, sha_pass_hash, ... ) 
VALUES ('Meko','7c4d046a92c441c426ce86f15fa9ecd1fc1fd5f1', ... )
```

Then to check for the existence of that row, given:

```
 $user_username = 'Meko' ;
 $user_password = '1234' ;
```

Then your query to check for the existence of the row would be something like this:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT ... 
           FROM account a
          WHERE a.username      = ?
            AND a.sha_pass_hash = ?';
```

calculate the password hash, the same way as when it was originally done

```
 $user_sha_hash = sha1( $user_username . ':' . $user_password) ;
```

And prepare and execute the query, passing in the SHA checksum string

```
 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->bindValue(1, $user_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->bindValue(2, $user_sha_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->execute();
 if( $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      //
 } else {
      //
 )
 $sth->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Although I like how through your answer is, it really must mention that now's a perfect time to fix the password problem using a proper [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) method like [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). SHA1 is completely inadequate.

Comment: I didnt make the login registration in the first place. Im trying to code a small website for a World of Warcraft game server which had a default registration page and I got assigned to make a website we could use. Even thou we only are 50 people on the servet

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify explicitly but assuming that your sha_pass_hash contains a hashed value of the following format: hash(username:password) then hash '$user_username' + ":" + '$user_password' first and then compare it to your password.

Comment: This really isn't an answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
$search = $username.":".$password;
$query = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE password = ".$search;
```

**IMPORTANT:**

I very much hope you are preparing your statements and binding your parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks. If you are not, let me know and I can help you out in more detail so that your database is secure.

Also, I recommend that you create another table and fill it in with the values inside this `account` table. The previous answer is a quick fix so that your users can login meanwhile, but by no means should the previous table stay as it is.

Let me know if you need any more help :)

Comment: Im only a beginner with php. The example above doesnt work. I tried several times and It wasnt a writing error. By preparing my statements. Do you mean I need to use sql escape? :)

Comment: It's not a problem if your a beginner. Could I see how you implemented my previous code?